# How to pin 1 corner of image to rotate around that pin?

Tags: image

One vertex is correct. How to use that as a pivot point to Square image to XY plane?

Comment: You should post an image describing what you want to do. Try snapping the 2D cursor to the vertex and then setting the translation to 2D cursor.

Comment: .. or, if you want to do it in Edit Mode, maybe the  '.' (period) shortcut to set the pivot.. > 'Active Element'

Comment: Robin tyty solved. Ron, being so new, I'm unsure how to recreate these steps

Comment: IMO this question could do with some clarity. There is every chance that editing vert locations of a plane in edit mode will skew its local axes, and could be the case that setting rotation on the object has the desired effect.